# With which plugin should I create the Laravel project?

Tags: laravel, web-services, oauth, ldap, project

I am creating a new project which will use LDAP, web service and OAuth to authenticate users.

I will also have to use the role system.

With what technology could I create the project?

Laravel + Fortify, Laravel + JetStream or Laravel full custom

Thanks greetings.

I have tried to create it with laravel jetstream, but I have had to modify a lot of code in the laravel/jetstream project structure and it gets very messy.

The problem is that I have to work with a lot of LDAP, Web service and OAuth connections.

LDAP users will be authenticated by identification document, some of them with email.

It will be a mixed authentication system.

**So the question is if I create the project using jetstream, fortify, or a fully customized project without using those templates.**

Answer (score 0):

If you want use ldpa auth you can use adldap2/adldap2-laravel package with standart laravel project

```
composer require adldap2/adldap2-laravel
```

In my case installed openldap,phpLDAPadmin tools also
Then change auth provider driver like this:

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'ldap',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],
],
```

Also ldap service creditionals in env file in my case:

```
LDAP_HOSTS="openldap"
LDAP_USERNAME=""
LDAP_PASSWORD=""
LDAP_BASE_DN=""
```

And other changes

I used this packages years ago with custom auth system but now I prefer use jetstream for that. You can use fortify for more control of frontend and auth funcionality if yours not standart authonticate system

Comment: The problem is that I have to work with a lot of LDAP, Web service and OAuth connections.

LDAP users will be authenticated by identification document, some of them with email.

It will be a mixed authentication system.

So the question is if I create the project using jetstream, fortify, or a fully customized project without using those templates.

Comment: You can use jetstream. if you want  complete control of the styling and functionality then fortify wil be your choose